# Is php false defined as zero?

Tags: php

`if (0)` always returns **false** . And `if(false)` also returns **false**. I can't understand these difference. In both the cases what actually if returns? Is it **NULL** or any thing else?

Comment: read this  > http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

false == 0 but false !== 0

Comment: PHP is loosely typed, so these values are considered equivalent, but not the same. If you try `if ( 1 === true)` it would return false. The `===` means "same value, not just equivalent".

Comment: If `floor(3)` returns the same as `floor(3.9)`, does `3` equal `3.9`?

Answer (score 3):

`false` is [boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) , `0` is [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) , and [NULL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) represents a variable with no value .

In the [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) construct

```
    if( expression ) statement;
```

[if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) expects the [expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) to be [boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) so [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) `0` evaluates to [boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) `false` .

More info :

> A value in most cases will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires a [boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) argument.

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered **FALSE**:

- the [boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) **FALSE** itself
- the [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) 0 (zero)
- the [float](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) 0.0 (zero)
- the empty [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), and the [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) "0"
- an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with zero elements
- an [object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type [NULL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) (including unset variables)
- [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) objects created from empty tags

Every other value is considered **TRUE** (including any [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)).

For more information check [Booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) .

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you do compare `[0, null, false, "", array(), etc]` with something existing or something not empty.

PHP is not a strongly typed language. Look at the false when nonstrict comparison (==) as something like this:

`0` apples it is no apples then `false (has apples more then 0? No)`.

`array()` - `false (set is not empty? No)`.

`""` - `false (has string symbols? No)`

Comment: I don't think the argument that PHP is strongly typed is the best way to explain the behavior. Consider Python: it's strongly typed but it behaves the same way.